# ¿Cómo hago para asignarle valores a las propiedades del objeto?

Tags: javascript, objeto

```
function Usuario(opciones) {
this.usuario = opciones.usuario;
this.nombre = opciones.nombre;
this.email = opciones.email;
this.password = opciones.password;

Usuario.prototype.saludar = function() {
    return 'Hola, mi nombre es ' + this.nombre;
  };
```

Buenas noches! Este código es la solución a un ejercicio. Estoy comenzando en este mundo de la programación web y necesito su ayuda. Yo quedé sorprendido al ver la solucón del ejercicio porque no me habían enseñado esta manera de construir un objeto en **Javascript**, ni tampoco la había visto yo en internet.
"**opciones**" es **objeto** y está en el **parámetro** de la `function` constructora "**usuario**". *Esto me desanimó por no entenderlo y apesar de que busque sobre el tema en internet, no encontré nada.* 
Entiendo los cuatro `this`.**propiedades** *(son las propiedades del **objeto** "**opciones"**)*, pero no así los **valores** que tienen **opciones.usuario** y demás. 
Mi otra duda es: ¿Cómo asignarle variables a las cuatro propiedades del **objeto**? 
usuario: DiReiss.
nombre: Reiss.
y así. 
Espero puedan ayudarme porque todo el día estuve atorado en esto y en verdad quiero aprender antes de seguir avanzando a los callbacks.

Comment: Los 4 `this` no hacen referencia a las propiedades del objeto `opciones`, hacen referencia a las propiedades del objeto Usuario (en Javascript las funciones son un tipo de objeto). Por lo tanto `this.nombre = opciones.nombre;` es una asignación del valor de la propiedad `nombre` que hay o existe en el objeto opciones a la propiedad `nombre` del objeto Usuario. Es por ello que, la función o método `saludar` utiliza `this` para referirse a la propiedad del Objeto Usuario. El constructor sólo utiliza el objeto `opciones` para crear la instancia de Usuario con los valores adecuados. Saludos

Comment: Has visto el la documentacion de [developer mozilla?](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this)